# Know when AWS SNS topic was created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudtrail

Is there any way to know when AWS SNS topic was created?

For example, EC2 gives this info in AWS console ("Launch time" field in "Instance details" tab):

[image: EC2 "Instance details" tab]

**But SNS doesn't provide this info about topic:**

[image: SNS topic details]

I tried CloudTrail but its event history is only 90 days long.

Is any way to find a topic creation time that is older than 90 days?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. It depends on whether you created a Trail, or used the default 90-day trail.

When AWS CloudTrail was first released in 2013, it required the Trail to be activated before it stored data. However, many users didn't turn it on, so in 2017 they [automatically activated it for the past 7 days](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/aws-cloudtrail-event-history-now-available-to-all-customers/) without having to setup a Trail. It was later extended to 90 days (it seems).

From [Viewing Events with CloudTrail Event History - AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html):

> You can troubleshoot operational and security incidents over the past 90 days in the CloudTrail console by viewing Event history... For information on creating a trail so that you have a record of events that extends past 90 days, see [Creating a trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html) and [Getting and Viewing Your CloudTrail Log Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/get-and-view-cloudtrail-log-files.html).

So, if you created the Trail yourself, then the full history is there (forever!). However, the console only goes back 90 days so you can retrieve the information from the log files themselves.

Comment: What if i cant find it even in the trail? 
Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/73328834/13126651