# How to find who created a SNS Topic in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

**What**:- I am trying to find who created(user or Cloudformation) an SNS topic name dynamodb to find its purpose.

The SNS topic has no subscriptions or tags.

**information i have about topic**:- arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:dynamodb and topic's **access policy**

**Things I tried**:-

- There is a cloud trail enabled for the account that logs events in the s3 bucket.
- Create an Athena table and run queries, but I couldn't find any log entry for that SNS topic.

My query

```
SELECT * FROM "default"."cloudtrail_logs_jatin_members_xxxxxxxx" where event name = 'CreateTopic' limit 100;
```

**Is there any alternate way to find who created this SNS topic?**

Comment: you could probably check in Cloud Trial if it's enabled or in Event History if it's created within two weeks.

Comment: @Sri, i assume you have read my question, because i have clearly mentioned in `things i tried` about cloudtrail